# Using React, what is an easy way to load files based off clicking buttons with the same name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I once made a site in jQuery. On this site, you customize characters, and the image would load depending on what you pick. Behind the scenes, the file name was copied from the menu options you click. For example...

Let's say you want an skinny female. You go to the submenus and click "skinny," and you click "female." The program stores "skinny" and "female" from the option you just clicked (using `.text()`). It then updates the shown image to skinny-female.svg using simple concatenation. The site is here...

http://matiny.altervista.org/VI/vice-bodies/

With react, I'm already confused since you have to store images in variable names, not file paths. I need a way to split the variable names, like in the above example. Then the variable names can be put back together based off user choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the image names in state variables whenever the user clicks on the corresponding button, using `event.target.innerText`. Then, the `src` attribute of the image could be setup based on those state variables.

Something Like this:

```
import React from 'react';

class ImageSelector extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      imageName1: '',
      imageName2: ''
    }
  }

  render() {

    let imgSrc = this.state.imageName1 + '-' + this.state.imageName2 + '.svg';

    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={(ev) => this.setState({ imageName1: ev.target.innerText})}>skinny</button>
        <button onClick={(ev) => this.setState({ imageName2: ev.target.innerText})}>female</button>
        <img src={imgSrc} />
      </div>
    );

  }
}
```